# How do you get positive and negative rows based on date

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to get ordinance by the current date from a table.  this query does what I want but it seems overkill:

```
WITH     dates
AS       (SELECT Month,
                 FQ,
                 FY,
                 MonthDisplay,
                 CAST (datepart(yyyy, [Month]) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + RIGHT(CAST ((datepart(MM, [Month]) + 100) AS VARCHAR), 2) AS YM,
                 fh,
                 LEFT(CONVERT (VARCHAR, [Month], 100), 3) + ' ' + RIGHT(fy, 4) AS MY,
                 LEFT(CONVERT (VARCHAR, [Month], 100), 3) AS ShortMonthName
          FROM   Pipeline.DimTime AS dt),
         datesafter
AS       (SELECT dt.FH,
                 dt.FQ,
                 dt.FY,
                 dt.MY,
                 dt.Month,
                 dt.MonthDisplay,
                 dt.ShortMonthName,
                 dt.YM,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [Month]) AS RowNum
          FROM   dates AS dt
          WHERE  dt.[Month] >= (SELECT TOP 1 DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, ds.SnapshotDate), 0)
                                FROM   dbo.vw_DimSnapshot AS ds
                                WHERE  ds.SnapshotWeek = 'Current')),
         datesbefore
AS       (SELECT dt.FH,
                 dt.FQ,
                 dt.FY,
                 dt.MY,
                 dt.Month,
                 dt.MonthDisplay,
                 dt.ShortMonthName,
                 dt.YM,
                 (ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [Month] DESC)) * -1 AS RowNum
          FROM   dates AS dt
          WHERE  dt.[Month] < (SELECT TOP 1 DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, ds.SnapshotDate), 0)
                               FROM   dbo.vw_DimSnapshot AS ds
                               WHERE  ds.SnapshotWeek = 'Current'))
SELECT   *
FROM     datesafter
UNION ALL
SELECT   *
FROM     datesbefore
ORDER BY [month];
```

Comment: you can make an order by a datetime type variable that it'll order all by the date value

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it in a single query by using datediff. Pass current date as one parameter and the table date as another.  This will work if you are ok with skipping missing dates.  For example if current date is Nov 21, then Nov 20 will show up as -1 and Nov 18 will show up as -3 even if Nov 19 is missing in the data. I am not sure what your business requirement is, so cannot comment beyond that.

And by the way if you are looking for ordinance based on months instead of day, you can use still use datediff but use the correct datepart (See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).

HTH.
-Tabrez